# Change Tablayout image from Viewpager Swipe

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, adapter, android-tablayout

/*
Hello everyone who read this Im trying to do something simple.
Im creating a slide show. 
I have a view pager with a tablayout. 
The Tablayout is going to be used as an indicator for the viewpager. 
My problem is setting the background drawable for the selected tab within the view pager.
I tried to get the tab layout position and set the background drawable but thats not working so well. 
I posted a code if you need anymore information just let me know.
*/

```
 public class TutoralActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutoral);

            int images[] = {
                    R.drawable.t1,
                    R.drawable.t2,
                    R.drawable.t3,
                    R.drawable.t4
            };

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_dot_indicator);

            MyCustomAdapter customAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(TutoralActivity.this, images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(myDrawableImage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });

            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        }

        private class MyCustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            Context context;
            int images[];
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

            public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int[] images) {
                this.context = context;
                this.images = images;
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                View imageViewLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_layout, container, false);

                ImageView imageToShow = (ImageView) imageViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_image);
                imageToShow.setImageResource(images[position]);

                Button btnDone = (Button) imageViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnImageDone);
                btnDone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                container.addView(imageViewLayout);

                return imageViewLayout;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return images.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by **not working so well?**

Comment: @AyushKhare I was missing a line of code the onPageSelected method I want to change set the icon with a custom drawable however its no setting the background image

Comment: @AyushKhare I figured it out thanks